# SQL Server Profiler file won't open trace file

Tags: sql-server

I talked a customer through running a Profiler trace and have them 
send it to me.

But of course, even though we're both running 2014, I can't open it. Profiler complains it can't open files from before 2006. So then I tried the recommended trick:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fn_trace_gettable('C:\xyz\trace.trc', default);
```

And that says it can't connect to the database. Yes, there is a file in that location.

Is there any canonical solution to this problem?

Comment: Is that file **on the server machine** at that specified location? A remote SQL Server machine cannot just access your local `C:\` drive (and that's a **good thing!**)

Comment: Surely your client isn't running SQL Server 2005, as that might imply though, either, right?

Comment: Try inserting it into a temp table first... `SELECT * INTO temp_trc FROM fn_trace_gettable('C:\xyz\trace.trc', default);` See if that gets you what you want.

Comment: @Larnu - the client is running 2014, as mentioned.

Comment: @marc_s - yes, the file is on my C drive which is also the machine with the server.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - that did it! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting it into a temp table first...

```
SELECT * INTO temp_trc FROM fn_trace_gettable('C:\xyz\trace.trc', default);
```

This should get you what you want.